# what is the best way to delete 1000's of folders based on created date?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a task to do on the 30th of this month that requires me to manually go through thousands of folders in a directory and delete any and all folders and files in the folders that were created on a certain date.

I'm thinking i can write a quick program that will handle this for me. I have a winform with a text box for my UNC path, a date time picker to pass the date through and a button to delete the files. so far I just have this and I want to be sure that I'm on the right path.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class FormMain

    Private Sub btn_DeleteFolders_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_DeleteFolders.Click
        Dim UNC As String = tb_UNC.Text
        Dim FDate As String = dt_FolderDate.Value.Date
        Dim FPath As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(UNC)
        Dim CreatedDate As String = way to find the created date of a folder??
        'MessageBox.Show(FPath)

        For Each f As String In Directory.EnumerateFiles(UNC, FDate, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            If FDate = CreatedDate Then

                File.Delete(UNC)

            End If
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

any help would be awesome!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FileInfo` class has the creation date for the file, so try this instead:

```
Dim compareToDate As DateTime = CType(dt_FolderDate.Value.Date, DateTime)
Dim files As String() = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirName)

For Each file As String In files
    ' Create object to hold file information
    Dim fi As New FileInfo(file)

    ' Compare the creation date to the date selected in the date picker
    If fi.CreationTime.Date = compareToDate.Date Then
        ' The dates match, so delete the file
        fi.Delete()
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Note that this code `fi.CreationTime = compareToDate` will only delete those files that where created at the exact TIME on that date.  I'm guessing that you want to delete any file created on that date.

Comment: correct. any folder that was created on the date. the files inside might have been created long ago but the folder would have been created on the specified date and needs to be deleted along with the files inside.

Comment: Avoid using `Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(dirName)` as this will iterate through all the folders immediately causing your program to halt. Instead, use `Dim files As String() = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirName)` which will retrieve the folders as you iterate through them.

Comment: @DaveMichener - updated answer to just use the `Date` portion of the `DateTime` object.

Comment: @alstonp - updated code to use `EnumerateFiles()` as the OP originally had.

Comment: @BSanders - the `FileInfo` class contains information about a single file, such as the `Directory` it is located in, the `Extension` the file has and, in your case, the `CreationTime` for when the file was actually created. Read [FileInfo Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo_properties.aspx) for Microsoft's documentation of this class.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. it's not exactly working but it's got me on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

The FileInfo class contains a property that will tell you this. Here's the code in C# but it should be easily converted into VB.

```
using System.IO;

private DateTime GetCreationdDate(string FolderPath)
{
    FileInfo FI = new FileInfo(FolderPath);
    return FI.CreationTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
    Dim sPath As String = "P:\ToDropBox"
    Dim dtCreateDate As Date
    For Each SFolder As String In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(sPath)
        dtCreateDate = IO.Directory.GetCreationTime(SFolder)
        If dtCreateDate.ToShortDateString = Now.ToShortDateString Then
            Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C rd /s " & SFolder)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Sample deletes folders made "today" so you don't want that.... I'd put in some date limit checks to be sure.

The DOS command prompts for a y/n, I think there is a switch to suppress that if you are brave. If the path has spaces you will need to wrap the path in double quotes.
http://ss64.com/nt/rd.html